# Extending Twig in Bolt.cm

Tags: twig, bolt-cms

I would like to extend core Twig in Bolt cms with 
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/text.html

What is best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done by creating a [simple Bolt extension](https://docs.bolt.cm/extensions/config):

```
<?php
namespace Bolt\Extension\Gawain\MyTwigExtension;

class Extension extends \Bolt\BaseExtension
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return "MyExtension";
    }
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->addTwigFunction('foo', 'twigFoo');
    }
    public function twigFoo()
    {
        $html = "<p>bar</p>";
        return new \Twig_Markup($html, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these auto-loaded by bolt into twig then?

Comment: Yes, details in the extension documentation.

Comment: In your custom extension, you have access to Twig_Environment through the service provider. In your initialize() method you can call $this->app['twig']->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text()). Just make sure you've included the twig/extensions package in your main composer.json file. If you do it this way, you don't have to use $this->addTwigFunction().

Comment: The link is no longer valid.